# How are more sub-figures with letters usualy cited?

Tags: citation-style, formatting

We are writing a book so we want to establish some guidelines, so I am looking for how this is most usualy done in scientific papers.

What would be the rules for citing more sub-figures with letters? What is more usualy used, without space, like this:

> Fig. 33b,c

or with space, like this? :

> Fig. 33b, c

Thank you!

Comment: Not worth a lot of fuss about. A publisher will have a style guide. In the meanwhile look at some books in your field and do what they do.

Comment: @EthanBolker I am the publisher!! :-) I am creating those style guides now. Not easy to find such example, that's why I'm asking...

Comment: If you're using LaTeX you can write a macro for this and postpone the formatting decision.

Comment: For IEEE, it is 33(b), 33(c)